# How to create a content section beside a vertical menu in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, side-menu

I am trying to create a template so i need an editable region div (red box) beside the side menu (blue box) to put content inside. I can't figure out how though. every thing I tried either hides the menu or the new div I created. I am really new to this thing I would appreciate any help with achieving this or let me know if it is even possible. [rough sketch of what I want the site to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Vcw.png)

This is the code for the side menu.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
p, ul, li, div, nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Calibri;
}
#menu {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.parent-menu {
  background-color: #0c8fff;
  min-width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #007ee9;
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  transition: left 200ms ease-in;
}
#menu ul li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
  transition: left 200ms ease-in;
}
#menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="CSS/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<h3>CSS3 Vertical Menu With Sub Menus</h3>
<nav id="menu">
  <ul class="parent-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home & Kitchen</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item3 with submenu</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Even more</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Electronics</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Clothing</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Cars & Motorbikes</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Books</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Deliveries</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T&C</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a third div and give it a class or ID (I'll just call it Green Box), and put the other two divs inside the third one.
After that give Green Box a  `display: inline;`. With that, the divs will be able to be next to eachother.

If that hasn't solved it yet, you can try to change the `margin` of the Red and Blue Box.

Comment: I tried that the problem is the side menu nav tag width stretches all the way across the page because of the menu items that come out when user hovers. I was hoping there is a way to overlay the nav element over the redbox while making the redbox still visible. then when the menu items come out they will cover the content (red box) temporarily. (I wouldn't mind a suggestion to make the side menu another way to make this structure possible as well). Thank you

Comment: Maybe if you add a Z index? But I'm not sure about that.
What you also could do is get rid of nav tags, since that they only have a use for screen readers. Or what my last option would be, is maybe to make the nav tag invisible or hidden? When they're hidden they don't take space anymore. I hope this helps!

Also, you could use `margin-top: -100px`, on the -not navigation- div, that way you force the div to get higher